# Unable to fetch dropdownlist value in FLASK

Tags: html, mongodb, flask

I the following code I am unable to fetch the option value in my python code from my HTML code.
I am dynamically adding data to my drop-down list.

```
    <form name="info-form" method="POST">
        <select id="record" name="val" width="600px">
            <option SELECTED value='0'>Select a name to view info</option>  
            {% for i in data %}
             <option name= "abc" value= '{{ i.name }}'>{{i.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type= "submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

This my ajax method in script file to redirect the page:

```
$("form[name=info-form").submit(function(e){
 var $form = $(this);
 var $error = $form.find(".error");
 $.ajax({
  url: "/info/",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(resp) {
    window.location.href = "/info/";
   }
   ,
   error: function(resp) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
e.preventDefault();
});


    @app.route("/info/", methods =['GET','POST'])
    def info():
     if request.method == 'POST':
      data = []
      pname =request.form.get('nm')
      data = db.users.find({ "name" : pname })
      print(pname)
      return render_template('recieve.html', data = data)
    else:
      gname = request.args.get('nm')
      print(gname)
      return render_template('recieve.html')
```

Is there any problem with get and post? I am redirecting my URL to '/info/' using Jquery and AJAX.
in gname as well as pname I am getting None. I am not understanding why is it so?

I want to send the selected value to pymongo query to get the values which I will redirect to another page.

Comment: Default method is GET, so try adding a if request.method == 'POST' to the info function.

Comment: Tried that but I am getting this: "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

Comment: You also have to return something when it is a GET method. Show your code here please?

Comment: @app.route("/info/", methods =['GET','POST'])
    def info():
     if request.method == 'POST'
         data = []
         print(request.form.get("val"))
         data = db.selectingASingleFieldDemo.find({ "name" : request.form.get("val")})
         return render_template('recieve.html', data = data)

Comment: Please add this to your question, it is impossible to see indentation this way.

Comment: I am just adding if request.method == 'POST' after def info()

Comment: @gittert I have made the changes in the code above. Please let me know if you can figure out anything?

Comment: yeah, tested part of your code here. I would recommend reverting to your original code, method = 'post' is not necessary. Just wondering, is the issue that your pname statement is not working? I think you should change this to pname =request.form.get('val'), as val is the name of the selection menu in your template. For instance do a print (request.form) to see the immutabledict. Please elaborate more what the exact issue is, as I find it difficult to understand, I also might me missing the use case here.

Comment: Thanks @gittert I did action = {{ url_for }} in the form and didn't redirect the URL using AJAX so now things are working fine.